# is missing a template for request formats: text/html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> I have Term and Phrase models and I am adding Nested Resources. I want to get the Term Id for Phraes_term to create a data pair
>
> Example: Term 1 and Phrase 2.
> But when you press the new button from show.html.erb term, an error will occur

```
-->error :PhrasesTermsController#new is missing a template for request formats: text/html
```

form.html.erb
-(phrases_term).

```
<%= form_with(model: phrases_term, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if pharases_term.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(pharases_term.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this phrase from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% pharases_term.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :ID %>
    <%= form.number_field_tag :ID %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

(phrases_term)
-new.html.erb

```
<%= render 'form', phrases_term: @phrases_term %>
```

Phrases_terms_controller.rb

```
class PhrasesTermsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_term

  def new
    @phrases_term = PhrasesTerm.new
  end

  def create
    @phrases_term = @term.phrases_term
    @phrases_term.user = current_user
    @phrases_term.save
    redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
  end
  
  private
  
  def phrases_term_params
    params.require(:phrases_term).permit(:term_id)
  end

  def set_term
    @term = Term.find(params[:term_id])
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :terms do
    resources :phrases_terms, only: [:create, :destroy, :new]
  end
```

(Term)
Show.html.erb

```
<td><%= link_to 'New', new_term_phrases_term_path(@term) %></td>
```

```
(phrases_term).

_form.html.ebr
<%= form_with(model: phrases_term, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if pharases_term.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(pharases_term.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this phrase from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% pharases_term.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :ID %>
    <%= form.number_field_tag :ID %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

```
(phrases_term)
 new.html.erb
<%= render 'form', phrases_term: @phrases_term %>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This means you do not have a app/views/phrases_term(s)/new.html.erb file. I'm unsure if you've namespaced the files under 'phrases_term' or 'phrases_terms'.

Make one in the correct directory, populate it, and it will load.